# I need a solution for clean the attachment files uploaded when I test with RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, carrierwave, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Hello guys I'm using RSpec for testing and I have some test for upload files using factories. 
I set up the database cleaner but, when I do a tree on the public folder it's creating a new file everytime and I want to clean this everytime I run the rspec command.

```
tree public
public
├── 404.html
├── 422.html
├── 500.html
├── attachment
├── favicon.ico
├── robots.txt
└── uploads
    ├── attachment
    │   └── file
    │       ├── 1
    │       │   ├── photo.jpg
    │       │   ├── photo02.jpg
    │       │   └── photo03.jpg
    │       ├── 10
    │       │   └── photo03.jpg
    │       ├── 11
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 12
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 13
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 14
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 15
    │       │   └── photo03.jpg
    │       ├── 16
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 17
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 18
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 19
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 2
    │       │   ├── photo.jpg
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 20
    │       │   └── photo03.jpg
    │       ├── 21
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 22
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 23
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 24
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 25
    │       │   └── photo03.jpg
    │       ├── 26
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 27
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 28
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 29
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 3
    │       │   ├── photo.jpg
    │       │   └── photo03.jpg
    │       ├── 30
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 31
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 32
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 33
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 34
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 35
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 36
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 37
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 38
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 39
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 4
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 40
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 41
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 42
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 43
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 44
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 45
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 46
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 47
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 48
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 49
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 5
    │       │   └── photo03.jpg
    │       ├── 50
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 51
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 52
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 53
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 54
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 55
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 56
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 57
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 58
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 59
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 6
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 60
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 61
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 62
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 63
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 64
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 65
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 66
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 67
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 68
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 69
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 7
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 70
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 71
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 72
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 73
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 74
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       ├── 75
    │       │   └── photo02.jpg
    │       ├── 8
    │       │   └── photo.jpg
    │       └── 9
    │           └── photo02.jpg
    ├── post
    └── tmp
```

So for configure the database cleaner I put in the spec/support/database_cleaner.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :deletion
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:deletion)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

my rails_helper:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'
require "pundit/rspec"


# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, in
# spec/support/ and its subdirectories. Files matching `spec/**/*_spec.rb` are
# run as spec files by default. This means that files in spec/support that end
# in _spec.rb will both be required and run as specs, causing the specs to be
# run twice. It is recommended that you do not name files matching this glob to
# end with _spec.rb. You can configure this pattern with the --pattern
# option on the command line or in ~/.rspec, .rspec or `.rspec-local`.
#
# The following line is provided for convenience purposes. It has the downside
# of increasing the boot-up time by auto-requiring all files in the support
# directory. Alternatively, in the individual `*_spec.rb` files, manually
# require only the support files necessary.
#
 Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migration and applies them before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  #
  # You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
  # explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
  #
  #     RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  #       # ...
  #     end
  #
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  # arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
  # config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("gem name")

  # Include Factory Girl syntax to simplify calls to factories
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
    config.integrate do |with|
      # Choose a test framework:
      with.test_framework :rspec
      # Or, choose the following (which implies all of the above):
      with.library :rails
    end
  end

  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers, type: :feature
  config.after(type: :feature) { Warden.test_reset! }
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
end
```

my factory of attachments.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :attachment do
    transient do
      file_to_attach "spec/fixtures/photo.jpg"
    end

    file { File.open file_to_attach }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I went about it in a recent project of mine:

In `config/initializers/carrierwave.rb`

```
if Rails.env.test?
  Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/uploaders/*.rb"].each { |file| require file }

  CarrierWave::Uploader::Base.descendants.each do |klass|
    next if klass.anonymous?
    klass.class_eval do
      def cache_dir
        "#{Rails.root}/spec/support/uploads/tmp"
      end

      def store_dir
        "#{Rails.root}/spec/support/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and in `spec/spec_helper.rb`

```
config.after(:each) do
  FileUtils.rm_rf(Dir["#{Rails.root}/spec/support/uploads"])
end
```

Comment: Hello Daniel Friss, firstly thank's you for reply! And I'm trying do with your configuration and I'm getting an error when I test and I think this is the folder that I changed. Look: `Admins can create posts with multiple attachments
     Failure/Error: raise ActionController::RoutingError, "No route matches [#{env['REQUEST_METHOD']}] #{env['PATH_INFO'].inspect}"

     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [GET] "/Users/romenigld/workspace/projects/news_city/spec/support/uploads/attachment/file/7/photo.jpg"`

Answer (score 1):

I was seeking on the web and try to do this and it's working right now. 
I think the configuration is the ideal in my case. But if anyone see something that not agree please let me know!

I config on `config/initializers/carrierwave.rb`

```
if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.cucumber?

  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
   config.storage = :file
   config.enable_processing = false
  end

  CarrierWave::Uploader::Base.descendants.each do |klass|
   next if klass.anonymous?
   klass.class_eval do
     def cache_dir
       "#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/tmp"
     end

     def store_dir
       "#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
     end
   end
 end
end

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.asset_host = ActionController::Base.asset_host
end
```

And in my spec_helper.rb I add this:

```
 config.after(:each) do
   if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.cucumber?
     FileUtils.rm_rf(Dir["#{Rails.root}/public/uploads"])
   end
  end
```

Now after I run the rspec command my tree on public is this:

```
tree public
public
├── 404.html
├── 422.html
├── 500.html
├── attachment
├── favicon.ico
└── robots.txt
```

So it was removed the files who was created testing and now I notice another problem the files who was created in development mode was deleted and will be deleted every time I run the tests and this is no so good!!
If anyone can help me with this new problem? I will appreciate!

Comment: Properly because you have set `"#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/..."` as your dir for uploads in the test environment, which might be the same as your development environment. Try with `"#{Rails.root}/spec/support/uploads/..."` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing another things and I'm backing to code this project and now I setup for upload on different paths for the mode test and dev. So this was the solution. And for share the code. I'm posting this.
And Thank's Daniel Friis for the help.

config/initialize/carrerwave.rb

```
if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.cucumber?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.storage = :file
    config.enable_processing = false
  end

  # make sure our uploader is auto-loaded
  AttachmentUploader

  # use different dirs when testing
  CarrierWave::Uploader::Base.descendants.each do |klass|
    next if klass.anonymous?
    klass.class_eval do
      def cache_dir
        "#{Rails.root}/spec/support/uploads/tmp"
      end

      def store_dir
        "#{Rails.root}/spec/support/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
      end
    end
  end
end

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.asset_host = ActionController::Base.asset_host
end
```

and put on spec/rails_helper:

```
# Clean up uploaded files
  config.after(:each) do
    if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.cucumber?
      FileUtils.rm_rf(Dir["#{Rails.root}/spec/support/uploads"])
    end
  end
```